# If I have a British seamans book, do I still need a British transit visa to join my ship?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, transit-visas, seamans-book

I'm from Serbia and I had to take a British transit visa last time I joined my ship. I have since obtained the British seamans book and have worked for a UK-based company for 7 years on ships. Can I go from London to Southampton without a visa?

Comment: Your employers should be experts in this. I'm surprised they haven't told you the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> **Passport exemptions**: Passengers with a Seaman Book issued by Azerbaijan, Brazil,
>     France, India, Luxembourg, Moldova (Rep.), Russian Fed.,
>     Spain, Tanzania and Tunisia (which have ratified ILO
>     Convention 185) **or issued by countries that have ratified
>     ILO Convention 108**. The Seaman Book must
>     contain the name and title of the issuing authority, date
>     and place of issue and a statement that the document is
>     issued for the purpose of the relevant Convention. The
>     seaman must travel on duty.

The UK is a signatory to ILO Convention 108.

As such, you don't need a passport or visa to enter the UK